# I am writing a code to find out the difference between the total no. of 1s and 0s in a binary number, using Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, binary, integer, scanning

My input is, say,

```
4
1100
```

'4' here is the number of digits in the array.

I want it to scan arr[0]=1, arr[1]=1, arr[2]=0, arr[3]=0

but it is scanning arr[0]=1100
and then random garbage.
How to tackle this?

- random garbage meaning, arr[1]=-1627, arr[2]=66 and anything randomly.

I'm pretty sure though, that the rest of my code is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  
    int n,i,t,chk1,chk0,fin;
  scanf("%1d",&n);
  int arr[n];
  
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   scanf("%d",&arr[i]); 
  }
  i=0;
  chk1=0;
  chk0=0;
  do{
    if(arr[i]==0){
      chk0=chk0+1;}
   else{
     chk1=chk1+1;}
 
    i++;
  }while(i<n);

  
  if(chk1>chk0){
      fin=chk1-chk0;
  }
  else if(chk1<chk0){
      fin=chk0-chk1;
  }
  else{
fin=0;  
  }
  
  printf("%d",fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using an array here. Just set an `int` counter to zero, then read one character at a time (using, e.g., `getchar()`). Increment your counter every time this character is equal to `1`, and decrement it every time this character is equal to `0`.

Comment: Why aren't you storing binary numbers as binary? Instead of "decimal encoded binary" or whatever this format is called.

Comment: @r3mainer, i just tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  
 int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
int count,i,c;
count=0;
  i=1;
  do{
  c=getchar();
   if(c==1){
       count++;
   }
 else{
     count--;
     
 }

 i++;
  }while(i<=n);
 printf("%d",count);
  
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in the comments is very close to a correct solution. There were just two problems:

1. ```
   c=getchar(); if(c==1) { /* ... */ }
   ```

The return value from `getchar()` is — as you might expect — a character. If your input contains the character `'1'`, then `getchar()` will not return a value of 1, but the ASCII value corresponding to this character, which happens to be 49. The character `'0'` has an ASCII value of 48. But you don't need to remember these values, just put `'0'` and `'1'` in your code where you want these values, not `0` and `1`.

2. ```
   else{ count--; }
   ```

This line assumes that the only characters that `getchar()` will see are `'0'` and `'1'`. However, you will probably find that after your call to `scanf()`, there will still be a line break character waiting for you in the input buffer. You can either insert an additional call to `getchar()` before the `while()` loop to clear this character, or just explicitly check for `'0'` and `'1'` inside the loop.

Here's a fixed version of your code. I got rid of the variable `i`, because you might as well use `n` to count the input digits.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, c, count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n > 0) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '1') {
            count++;
            n--;
        }
        else if (c == '0') {
            count--;
            n--;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```